# What is the name for this type of curve?

Tags: terminology, frequency, oscillators, resonance

I encountered this curve in the notes for a physics experiment:

[image]

It was described by the equation
$$
A = \frac{kA_0}{m\sqrt{\left(\omega_0^2 - \omega^2\right)^2+(2\gamma\omega)^2}}
$$

EDIT: I think it might be a bode plot...?

Comment: Yes, it’s a Bode plot. Specifically, as the annotations indicate, it’s the resonant amplification of a damped simple harmonic system under sinusoidal forcing; you can find it derived in nearly any introductory vibrations text, Benson Tongue’s being an especially engaging one. (I derive it [here](http://john.maloney.org/Programming/pythonboing.htm) as example 8.)

Comment: Bode plot is a generic name referring to the meaning of argument and function value. It is not specific for the curve with the particular frequency dependence of a damped harmonic oscillator.

Comment: It is clearly an algebraic curve of degree $6$ (sextic). However, I am not sure it has a special name.

Answer (score 3):

I think (and a quick check did not suggest alternatives) that the most frequent name for that curve in the Physics community is not shorter than the *Resonance Curve of the forced and damped harmonic oscillator*.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Lorentzian (if squared to get intensity instead of amplitude)) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_line_shape#Lorentzian

Comment: A Lorentzian would be symmetric around the maximum. Even squared, it cannot be considered a Lorentzian.